# webvtt subtitles not displaying when served from a different server

Tags: jwplayer, webvtt

I'm unable to get webvtt subtitles to display (specifically in an Ionic app using JWplayer). I've found a .vtt online on a demo, and if I use this url the demo subtitles display fine:
https://brenopolanski.github.io/html5-video-webvtt-example/MIB2-subtitles-pt-BR.vtt

I downloaded this file and uploaded it to my own server, making sure that apache is serving the file as "text/vtt; charset=utf-8" using the htaccess file - but when trying to use the same file on a different server the subtitles don't display. I'm assuming this means that it is a problem with how the vtt files are served, rather than with the application code.

I used Postman to check the header responses, I'm not sure what else should make a difference other than the Content-Type. Screenshots below.

Any help on what the issue could be, or how to debug it would be much appreciated!

**Working:**

[image]

**Not Working:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Obviously (now) it was the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" setting this to "*" and now it works